# What is the difference between &nbsp; and space?

Tags: html, google-chrome

There are two snippets of HTML code:

1.

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

2.

```
<div> </div>
```

I run them in Chrome 43.0.2357.130m separately.

The first snippet's `div` has height(height=18px), but the second doesn't have height(height=0).

I wonder why they have different result.

Thank you:-)!

Answer (score 21):

&nbsp is a non-breakeable space. It means that it is always interpreted as a character. For exemple, two words separated with a &nbsp: will always stay together, but two words separated with a space can be separated by a new line if the container is too small.

A simple space is like "Meh, I'm here if you need me, but I can change if you want me too <3", a &nbsp is more "I'm ALWAYS here"

In you exemple, the space seems useless (no words before and after) so it desappear. The &nbsp is still here. Consider the &nbsp as the same way that if it was an invisible letter more than a space.

Comment: Plus one for the heart, adds quality and love <3.

Comment: So in other words, space is a unloyal hoe while nbsp is wifey material.

Answer (score 0):

Second one run in browser it doesn't calculate as any String so no style applied here. But `&nbsp;` calculate as one character space.